# What are all of the "foo" and "bar" -like variable names?

Tags: naming-conventions

So i'm writing some example code where I need to name fields, classes, interfaces etc..., which can be difficult when you don't have any functionality in mind. I usually resort to calling things `foo` or `bar`, or if i'm feeling adventurous, `foobar`; and that's a problem, because that's a very short list to work with. So what I need is a list of all of these variable names for describing nothing-things.

*I will freely admit this is rather silly, but this is still a programming problem*

Comment: IMHO if you are writing example code (for someone else to read and understand?) you should use meaningful names. Makes it much easier to understand if you are talking about `customer`s and `shop`s instead of `foo`s and `bar`s, even if the code is not specifically designed for a certain domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common list is *foo*, *bar*, *baz*, *qux*, *quux*, *quuz* etc.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable#General_usage